# Подготовка к олимпиаде

Tags: java, c++, pascal, олимпиада

Здравствуйте, учусь в 9-м классе, впервые участвую в олимпиаде по программированию. Олимпиада ориентирована на Pascal. Его я знаю плохо(Яву-лучше). Программное обеспечение, установленное на рабочем месте:

- Windows
- Far manager (Volkov Commander)
- Borland Pascal 7.0
- GNU C++
- Free Pascal 2.х.

---

1. Есть ли тут какое-то подобие компилятора Java?
2. Возможно ли за 10 дней научиться читать из файла и писать в него (если можно, то киньте ссылку)?

Comment: А-а-а! Волков!!!

По делу: за 10 дней можно только найти крякер интернета.

Comment: Возможно ли за 10 дней научиться читать из файла и писать в него    
   
с нуля с помощью офф. документации и наличии эрудированости - максимум полтора часа. С тонкостями и нюансами - намного дольше.

Comment: Простите, не удержался: не "Ява", а "Джава".

Comment: @delphist007 Это тонкости транскрипции: "Ява", "Джава", "Жаба", "Жаба душит"...

Лучше уж писать импортными буквами, во избежание разночтений

Comment: @alexlz, в любом случае, читать как "Ява" - некорректно.

Comment: @delphist007 А почему некорректно? Язык общения у нас русский, Вы говорите -- "остров Джамайка, остров Джава", а мне со школьного курса географии и книги про капитана Блада (не "Блуда" же) привычней "остров Ява, остров Ямайка".

Хотя к программированию данная тема отношения не имеет, но достало, что кругом "манагеры" и "мерчандайзеры" на "рисепшенах".

Comment: Давайте я тоже не буду удерживаться. Как правильно произнести "Jazz"? Йаазь?

Comment: Я изучал немецкий, а что касается русского языка, то в нём слово "язь" есть. Правда это рыба.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. нет
2. Воспользуйтесь GNU C++. Он наиболее приближен к Java из вышеперечисленного. Читать-писать из/в файл очень просто. См. [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/) или ф-ции [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/) - [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)

> Полные правила ТУТ

Требует яндекс.аккаунта. Не хочу регистрироваться!

Comment: >> Не хочу регистрироваться!
И не надо, это ссылка на вложение из письма, откроется только из акка автора %)

Comment: аааааааааа

Answer (score 1):

Жесть вообще, почему бы не обратиться к комитету олимпиады с заявлением (коллективным) и попросить включить в набор софта openJDK или Oracle JDK. В конце концов Java один из самых популярных языков программирования. Все равно же олимпиадные задачи с точки зрения программирования никто не разбирает, оценивается правильный результат и время.

Comment: Да вообще хрень какая-то. Меня больше удивляет э... уровень олимпиоников. Алгоритмы алгоритмами, языки языками, но вопрос про "научиться читать из файла за 10 дней" убивает. И эти люди идут на олимпиаду? Либо это троллизм какой-то, либо я слишком хорошо думаю :)

Comment: особенно для учащегося 9го класса, который знает джаву :)

Comment: Посмотрите его профиль и вопросы на этом форуме и все станет ясно , на сколько хорошо он знает джаву.

Comment: как бы плохо он не знал джаву любой комитет спокойно ставит любой бесплатный компилятор или IDE.

Comment: я написал, что знаю java ЛУЧШЕ, ЧЕМ PASCAL